# Where is the split in the wealth gap?

Tags: inequality, wealth, demographics

I've been curious where the split in the wealth gap has been over time, and if it was possible to graph it.

Put another way, at what net worth is the number of those worth more shrinking in proportion to the population and the number of those worth less growing in proportion to the population?

I would love to be able to put a number on this and also see a graph of it over time. If I'm misunderstanding anything in this, feel free to inform me I'm not an economics major.

Comment: "*Put another way, at what net worth is the number of those worth more shrinking in proportion to the population and the number of those worth less growing in proportion to the population?*" I am not sure I understand what you mean. Are you asking about the median net worth?

Comment: Yes actually that is what I was looking for XD Thanks for giving me the right way of saying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking for median net worth in the US over time. For some reason, I thought it was more complicated than that.